# EF Core 3.0 DB Query taking long time with Include

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.0

I have the below Entity Objects Defined in my app.

```
[Table("BookItemAssignment")]
public partial class ItemAsst
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public short? Status { get; set; }
    public int? ItemID { get; set; }
    public int? UserWWID { get; set; }

    public virtual Book bookEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Book.cs

```
[Table("BookItem")]
public partial class Book
{
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Book()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int? Author { get; set; }
        public int? TypeID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public short? Status { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<BookDetail> BookDetails { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}
```

BookDetail.cs

```
[Table("BookDetail")]
public partial class JobTrainingPlanBookDetailDetail
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public virtual BookItem BookItem { get; set; }
        public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the below query to load all necessary books with their details with below query. It's taking too long - like 20 minutes in some cases:

```
booksdetails = (from a in ctx.BookItemAssignments
                             .Include(x => x.BookItem)
                             .ThenInclude(x => x.BookDetails)
                             .ThenInclude(x => x.Book)
                where a.UserWWID.HasValue &&
                      lstWwid.Contains(a.UserWWID.Value) &&
                a.Status == 1
                select a).ToList();
```

You can assume lstwwid is a list of integers that will be passed in to the method.

I do not know why is it taking so long for just 3 includes. I agree my data in the `BookItemAssignments` table will be huge around 300K rows.

I guess its because of cartesian explosion but not sure how to optimize this query to run in efficient way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please paste the resulting sql queries from EF Core logging ?

Comment: How do I get the Query? I cannot find it in `booksdetails.Expression` or booksdetails.ToString()

Comment: [Significant Query Slowdown When Using Multiple Joins Due To Changes In 3.0 #18022](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18022)

Comment: try sql profiler perhaps !! OR here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception

Comment: we do not own the DB. we are just running the queries on it. So cannot run SQL profiler as I am not a sysAdmin on the SQL Server

Comment: @IvanStoev so its a known issue in EF Core 3 with fix in EF Core 5? and only work around is to re write the query. I am not sure how do we split this query into multiple ones..can you pls help

Comment: As you can see, it's EF Core 3.0 introduced issue, with no clear way to resolve. You should really wait them to provide solution or try workarounds. There is similar question on SO which I'm going to use as duplicate of yours, so you can take a look at what is suggested there as well.

Comment: I also do not see many workarounds around the web to rewrite multilevel includes. closest one I saw was this https://gist.github.com/smitpatel/d4cb3619e5b33e8d9ea24d3f2a88333a again, this didn't get me far...so, am I really stuck with nothing can be done here?

Comment: @Programmerzzz That's the intended "solution" by the EF Core team (post author Smit Patel is part of that team).

Comment: I tried to mimic that behavior for tracking and Buffered in my queries..as below.But somehow it improved nothing. 

var query1 = ctx.BookItemAssignments.Where(x => x.Status == 1 && x.UserWWID.HasValue && lstWwid.Contains(x.UserWWID.Value)).Include(x => x.BookItem);
var result1 = query1.ToList();
query1.ThenInclude(x => x.BookDetails).ThenInclude(x => x.Book).Load();
query1.ToList();

return result1

Not sure what am I missing.. I am not even sure which case should I use. Just picked tracking and Buffered as I do not have any special configs in my DBContext

Answer (score 0):

Try to log the query on console by copying this code on the dbcontext and replacing ‘connection-string‘ with yours:

```
       public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
    = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { builder.AddConsole(); });

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory) // Warning: Do not create a new ILoggerFactory instance each time
        .UseSqlServer(
            @"connection-string");
```

This would help you see the query output without sql profiler.

Read more about logging [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3)